# Jquery UI Sortable Serialize Lists Malfunction

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to dynamically create a list and make it sortable.

My first attempt at this didn't include the dynamic loading of the list data. I found a basic example to build on here :

> http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/wp-content/uploads/file/jquerydragdrop/

When the "lists" select  element changes I retrieve the integer value of a selection to retrieve tasks associated with the selected list.

This is what I have so far. In Firebug, the list is structured properly after it is loaded. I think the problem is where I am trying to make the list "sortable" after creating it in the getJSON call.

I've tried moving the "// set our listdiv ul as sortable and stuff"  code within the JSON call and outside it but still within the select onChange event.

The list is displayed but it isn't sortable. No errors. Bafflement.  :0

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

// our global buildlist var
var buildlist;  




$('#lists').change(function(){

    var selected = $("#lists option:selected");
    var listval = selected.val();
    buildlist = "<ul>";

    $.getJSON('getlist.php?cid='+listval, function(data) {

        for(var i =0;i<data.length;i++)
        {
            var item = data[i];

    //      alert(item.id+","+item.cid+","+item.task+","+item.position);

            buildlist = buildlist + "<li id='listtasks_"+item.id+"'>"+item.task+"</li>";
        } 
        buildlist = buildlist + "</ul>";

    $("#listdiv").html(buildlist);

       });  // end getJSON

// set our listdiv ul as sortable and stuff
    $("#listdiv ul").sortable({ opacity: 0.6, cursor: 'move', update: function(){
        var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&action=update'; 
        $.post("updatelist.php", order, function(){
        });                                                              
    }                                 
    });


});  // end of change lists select box

}); // end doc ready
```

and this is the html after loading a list

```
<div id="listdiv">
<ul>
<li id="listtasks_1">this is item 1</li>
<li id="listtasks_2">this is item 2</li>
<li id="listtasks_3">this is item 3</li>
<li id="listtasks_4">this is item 4</li>
<li id="listtasks_5">this is itme 5 </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate `sortable` AFTER building the list, inside your get success function. Right now you are doing it before you actually build the HTML, so there is no object to make sortable.

Comment: Thanks, all good now. I just confused myself at some point. David Hedlund got me calmed down and back on track. :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be placed within your `getJSON` callback. I know you say you've already tried it, but at least that's something that's definitely wrong with your code the way it is right now. Once that is changed, it works for me: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dsJ6X/).

If that really does not fix your problem, the problem must be elsewhere. We would probably need to see some more code.

Comment: Well...I KNOW I had it within the JSON callback...but perhaps I didn't save the file or something. Works like a charm now. *sigh* Thank you!